# What's wrong with my code? name is not defined?

Tags: python, list

Here I've defined a function that creates a list using the argument "number in list". I can use the function but when I try to print the list it says the variable isn't defined. Anytime I try to take the declared variables out of the defined function, it tells me local variable "i" referenced before assignment. Can someone help me get this code to work? Thanks!

```
def create_list(number_in_list):
    i = 0
    numbers = []
    while i < number_in_list:
        numbers.append(i)
        i += 1


print "How many numbers do you want in your list?"
value = int(raw_input("> "))
create_list(value)


print "The numbers: "
print numbers
for num in numbers:
    print num
```

Comment: Indent correctly, indent the function body

Comment: first, can you fix your indentation in the question? It is not easy to tell where it is. if you create `numbers` in your `create_list` it will not be in the same namespace/scope. and will not be accessible outside of the function.

Comment: Python depends on correct indentation. Most other languages don't. Most other languages just become unreadable messes if you don't indent.

Comment: My apologies about the indentation error. Some reason the code did not paste correctly with indentation in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `numbers` variable exists only in the function `create_list`. You will need to return that variable, and use the return value in your calling code:

Thus:

```
def create_list(number_in_list):
    i = 0
    numbers = []
    while i < number_in_list:
        numbers.append(i)
        i += 1
    return numbers     # <----
```

And in your main code:

```
numbers = create_list(value)
```

Comment: Ahh.. why didn't I think of that? -_- Brilliant answer. thanks!